# Получение ID группы в Телеграме по её @названию

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить ID группы в телеграме, зная её `@название`, используя Telegram Client API? Или каким-нибудь другим способом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [12]: import telebot

In [13]: bot = telebot.TeleBot('<token>')

In [14]: bot.get_chat('@ru_python_beginners').id
Out[14]: -1001105793906
```

Из документации [`get_chat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat), который вернёт [`Chat object`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat).